# How to use gdb to decode stack trace (show line numbers)

Tags: gdb

I know I can use `info line *<addr>` within gdb to decode a single line. But a stack trace has 10+ addresses. Is there an efficient way to let me copy and paste a list of addresses (also without the leading `*`) and it will list the filenames and line numbers much like the `bt` command but without the core dump?

Comment: What do you mean by: "like the `bt` command but without the core dump?"?  Are you saying that you have a backtrace that causes gdb to dump core?  Otherwise, why wouldn't you just use the `bt` command...

Comment: You could create a [user-defined command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html) that calls `info line *ARG` for all arguments.

Comment: @Andrew the bt command will decode the full stack trace. What I have is a list of pointers from stack but having to run "info line" manually is labor intensive and also disrupt the output with my inputs, which is not as clean as the simple bt output.

Comment: Doesn't `bt` already do this by default?  Or it's a list of pointers that isn't the current backtrace?

Comment: @rogerdpack, `bt` only works if you are debugging a core dump or a live program. Sometimes, you just have a debug file that contains a stack trace with addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion of @ssbssa, I wrote the following user-defined command that works for me.

```
define decode
  set $i = 0
  while $i < $argc
    eval "info line *($arg%d)", $i
    set $i = $i + 1
  end
end
```